# Fusion auth versus jose4j library for jwt using secp256k

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, dsa, secp256k1, jwt

I am a beginner in-terms of JWT libraries in programming.

How the keypair used (secp256k1) is related with the algorithmic header used for creation of JWT?

And why authfusion doesn't need an algorthmic header as such JWSAlgorithm.ES256K (nimbus library) or AlgorithmIdentifiers.ECDSA_USING_SECP256K1_CURVE_AND_SHA256 (jose4j 0.9.0)?

I am confused with these relations, please shed some light over it.